# Creation of ViewControllers by the storyboard vs. by alloc/init

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm using Xcode 6.3, Objective-C.

In my storyboard, I create a `UINavigationController`. I then create a `UIViewController` and assign it as the root controller of the `UINavigationController`. I then create a second `UIViewController`, and connect it to the first `UIViewController` with a "manual show" segue.

So my storyboard has a `UINavigationController` and two `UIViewControllers`, all wired up. I also have a button in the first `UIViewController` that has an action to display the second `UIViewController` (more on this in a bit....)

My question is this: When the app runs, are all the Controllers created all at once?

The underlying question is, when I tap the button to display the second `UIViewController`, using the usual `[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]`, does this second `UIViewController` already exist - by virtue of having been created when the storyboard was loaded and parsed?

Or, before doing the push, do I need to do a `[... alloc] init]` first?

I know that, if you're creating `UIViewControllers` programmatically, you certainly would need to do the `alloc` and `init`. But it's not clear to me whether the `alloc/init` is needed when the `UIViewController`s have been "created" in the storyboard?

Testing the connection using `[self performSegueWithIdentifier...]` seems to work: the second `UIViewController` is shown, and no explicit alloc/init was done. So it seems to me that the destination controller is created (alloc/init) by UIKit when the segue is performed. You don't need to do that part.

But if I want to show the second `UIViewController` using the `...pushViewController:controller...` approach, how would I get the pointer to it? The array of `UIViewController`s in the `UINavigationController` only has one element in it, not two - which makes sense: this array would have the second controller's reference added to it only when it was pushed onto the stack.

So, again, if I wanted to do a `...pushViewController:controller...`, and assuming the second `UIViewController` does exist (because it was created by the storyboard), how can I get the pointer to it - in the first controller?

Or, do I have to first explicitly create it with the "alloc/init", which of course gives me the pointer?

It seems to me that if the storyboard creates all the controllers, then references to them must exist somewhere.

And, if so, doing an "alloc/init" step on the second controller, when it already has been created by the storyboard, is redundant, correct?

Or, even though I created the second `UIViewController` in the storyboard, I still need to instantiate it with the "alloc/init" message?

Of course, doing a manual segue to the second controller doesn't make sense because you're not taking advantage of the `UINavigationController` and it's in fact redundant. So, to take advantage of navigation, you have to use the `...pushViewController:controller...` approach, which requires a pointer to this second controller. Which, naively, suggests an "alloc/init" is needed. But again, I don't understand why you need to the explicit creation of the class instance when the storyboard (if I understand it correctly) would have done that for me.

I know that doing "alloc/init" only creates the object; no attributes are set. For that, I'd need to `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. But then I am still creating this second controller manually, right? So the storyboard does not instantiate them for me at runtime?

I know the storyboard calls `initWithCoder` and then `awakeFromNib`, suggesting that the storyboard does in fact instantiate these objects when the app runs. But does it do so as a matter of course when the app runs, or do I still need to do something manually, explicitly? What I am still after is a pointer to the second controller to use in the push, and where/how I can get this pointer.

Sorry for the long question: I just want to be extra clear about what I understand so far and what my question is. Yes, I'm an iOS n00b - which is why I'm turning here for expert help. For which I thank you much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created UIViewControllers in storyboard, they seems to be initialized all at once. You don't need to alloc/init if you are using storyboards. Use segues. If you don't want use segues then use:

//Here we instantiated a view controller programmatically

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"View controller storyboard id"];
```

Set storyboard id in Storyboard (Identity inspector) :)

Then just add to Push a ViewController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Or if you are not using navigation controller:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this and it works, and makes logical sense as well because you're extracting what you need from the storyboard instance.

Comment: Using this code, after launching the new viewController, self.navigationcontroller is being nil

Answer (score 1):

> My question is this: When the app runs, are all the Controllers created all at once?

No, only the Initial Controller is created (the one with arrow in storyboard). If it is a `Navigation controller`, its root view controller will be created too.

> Or, before doing the push, do I need to do a [... alloc] init] first?

Yes, you have to `alloc init` your `ViewController` before push it in navigation stack. It has not been created yet.

Under the hood, if you use storyboard, it will call `initWithCoder:` to init your view controller. Then, you can set it properties via `prepareForSegue:` method.

If you use coding methods, just `alloc init` your controller, set it properties and `pushToViewController`

Simple, right ?

> how can I get the pointer to it - in the first controller?

Ya, via the `prepareForSegue:` method, your new controller is `segue.destinationViewController`

...

I think this is enough, my answer has cover almost all of your questions. If you need further explanation, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure why, if a ViewController exists in a storyboard, why it wouldn't be created when iOS load the storyboard XML file, parses it, and creates all the objects that are declared in it. Seems to me that if you're iOS, and you've just injested the storyboard XML file, you'd just cycle through all the tags - and thus create all the controllers - at once. Now, that's NOT to say that these controllers will be displayed. But they should be created.

But you've given me some ideas that I can experiment with - so I thank you for that!

Comment: No, Lew. They will not be created because it's not efficient. You're talking about create hundreds of `UIView` while launching an app and it will take forever to complete. In addition, these controllers are still not ready for use (they only have views, not data, so why create it ?). Also, some controllers and views are not created yet (because I like to code my views, not storyboard) so I have to check if it is already exist or not, right ?.... It will be chaotic if storyboard works like the way you think, TBH.

Comment: OK, sure, what you say does make perfect sense. Thanks for the clarification - appreciate it!